# Unable to Set workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have being doing research on why I am unable to set my workbook for the past couple of hours. What I am trying to do is go through each spreadsheet within a folder to refresh the data and import them using `Vlookup` at the `Set Book2 = workbooks("InfoPedia Page Views (ASG Compete)")` is when I am getting an error

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Please, if anyone can tell why my code isn't working, I would really appreciated it.

```
enter code here
Sub Test()

Dim Book2 As Workbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

For Each f In fso.getfolder("C:\Users\v-gazhan\Desktop\Infopedia Quality Project\Infopedia Quality Dashboard\Page Views").Files


  If LCase(fso.GetextensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsx" Then

    Set wb = xl.workbooks.Open(f.Path)

    '   Set the correct month
    wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Month_Name").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array _
        ( _
        "[Time].[Month Name].&[10]")

    With Application.WorksheetFunction

    If fso.getbasename(f.Name) = "InfoPedia Page Views (ASG Compete)" Then

        ***Set Book2 = workbooks("InfoPedia Page Views (ASG Compete)")***

        Set SearchRange = Book2.Sheets("Page Views Sorted Most to Least").Range("B:D")

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reference").Cells(1, 4).Value = .VLookup(Sheets("reference").Range("B1"), SearchRange, 3, False)

    End If

    End With

    wb.Close

  End If

Next

xl.Qu    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the same thing you did with `wb`: `Set Book2 = workbooks.open`

Comment: I think you're missing the extension, for example the .xlsx in "InfoPedia Page Views (ASG Compete).xlsx"

Comment: You are opening the workbook in the instance of Excel `xl` that you created, so you should use `Set Book2 = xl.workbooks("...`.  That said, why do you need another reference to the workbook when you already have `wb`?  And why are you creating another instance of Excel, nothing in your code suggests a need to do this?

Comment: Well, I found a macro online where I would be able to go through each spreadsheet within a folder to refresh without fully understand how it works. I am just trying to build on top of what I found... which is why I am having trouble with this... The original macro was just to open the spreadsheet and refresh it. What I want is to open the spreadsheet, refresh, and use vlookup to export that data. I thought the way to do that is to set book2 of the opened spreadsheet, so when I do the vlookup through VBA, I can reference where the search range is from... I hope this make sense! Thanks everyone!

Comment: If I understand correctly Chris, is that wb is already another instance of Excel, when setting book2, I am actually setting a third one, which I don't need to since wb is what I should be useing for the second workbook. I changed my formula to remove the Book2, and replaced it with just wb...

       Set SearchRange = wb.Sheets("Page Views Sorted Most to Least").Range("B:D")
    
       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reference").Cells(1, 4).Value = .VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("reference").Range("B1"), SearchRange, 3, False)

The set part went through fine, but I am getting stuck on vlookup now... @.@

Comment: IT WORKED!! seems like my vlookup was looking at a value that didn't exist. Thank you so much for your explaining Chris, you helped me figured this out!! :D